# Android pull up Animation

Tags: android, animation, interpolation

I have used the following XML for Pull Down animation.

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

Now I need an opposite action, i.e. the height will increase upward from zero to normal height giving an effect of pulling up. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try interchanging scales?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<scale
 android:duration="500"
 android:fromXScale="1.0"
 android:fromYScale="1.0"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 android:toXScale="1.0"
 android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

[Android Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) syntax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@[package:]anim/interpolator_resource"
android:shareInterpolator=["true" | "false"] >
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="float"
    android:toAlpha="float" />
<scale
    android:fromXScale="float"
    android:toXScale="float"
    android:fromYScale="float"
    android:toYScale="float"
    android:pivotX="float"
    android:pivotY="float" />
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="float"
    android:toXDelta="float"
    android:fromYDelta="float"
    android:toYDelta="float" />
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="float"
    android:toDegrees="float"
    android:pivotX="float"
    android:pivotY="float" />
<set>
    ...
</set>
```

Comment: The XML you provided will decrease the height and will vanish at last. My requirement is that the height of view will increase upward from zero to normal.

Comment: check the syntax and make changes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%"  />
```